# Firefox Quantum side-by-side with Firefox ESR on macOS?

Tags: macos, firefox

Is there a way to have both versions available on macOS? The top google result for "firefox quantum side-by-side" advises to use the portable version, which is of course windows-only.

I'm guessing all that does is use a separate profile directory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this seems to be the same problem users of devel and beta builds are facing, and the suggestion [there](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-dedicated-profile-firefox-nightly) seems to be to just use the profile manager and set up a new profile.

```
<path to...>/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -profilemanager
```

Mistakenly selecting the wrong profile will probably end badly (profile for legacy version being updated by the new version, and subsequently unusable by the old version; or the legacy version choking on the new version's profile)... To avoid this, the article above links to [another how-to](http://spf13.com/post/managing-multiple-firefox-profiles-in-os-x/) to create a wrapper scripts that launch a particular version with its appropriate profile. The TL;DR version of that is:

1. In Script Editor, make an OSA-script:

   do shell script "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P profileName"
2. Save as *Application Bundle*.
3. Edit the result's `Contents/Info.plist` to include `LSUIElement=1` key/value pair (I suggest using some plist editor or PlistBuddy to do so, hand-editing plists as suggested there is rarely a good idea).
4. Optional: you can customise the bundle's icon, but you'll need it in the `icns` format. The linked page for `img2icns` is dead, but there is something called `makeicns` in [homebrew](http://brewformulas.org/Makeicns)

Comment: I don't know about macOS, but in Windows and Linux you can launch `firefox` with the `-p profilename` param to point it to a specific profile. Create a couple of shell scripts/shortcuts that launch the correct version on the correct profile, and... :)